# Getting the total value of all items specified row with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the total worked hours for a person in my application.

I have these columns in my table:

`id, UserId, ProjectId, FromHr, ToHr, WorkedHrs, Status`

Every column is added each day by the user and the WorkedHrs will be the count between `FromHr` to `ToHr`.

I am now trying to get the value of multiple results for a total at the end of each month, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Hours WHERE UserId = '22' AND ProjectId = '44' COUNT(WorkedHrs)
```

I really do not understand why i'm not getting any results, is there another way to approach this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(WorkedHrs) FROM Hours WHERE UserId = '22' AND ProjectId = '44'
```

The anatomy of an SQL query is this:

```
SELECT [list of all the things that you want returned]
FROM [table]
WHERE [conditions]
```

If you want anything to be returned from mysql, it has to be in the `SELECT` part of the query.

Answer (score 1):

It should be as simple as doing the following:

```
SELECT SUM(WorkedHrs) AS TotalHoursWorked
FROM Hours
WHERE UserId = 22
AND ProjectId = 44;
```

Your desribed structure doesn't say that you have any date columns. If you want to sum hours for every month then you'll need to add a date column (e.g. `ActionDay`) after which you can filter results by modifying the query to be as follows:

```
SELECT UserId, ProjectId, SUM(WorkedHrs) AS TotalHoursWorked, DATE_FORMAT(ActionDay, '%Y-%m') AS Month
FROM Hours
WHERE UserId = 22
AND ProjectId = 44
AND YEAR(ActionDay) = 2015
AND MONTH(ActionDay) = 7
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ActionDay, '%Y%m');
```

Answer (score -1):

What I would do.

Create 3 tables(from I can see from your post) `users`, `hours` and `projects`.

In `users`, make a `total_hours_worked` column for every user.

When you then insert a `hours`-row, calculate the difference and add it to `users.total_hours_worked`. So it goes from 20 to 28(as an example).

Then when you need the `total_hours_worked` just get it from `users`.

The server responds faster, and it does not have to calculate every time.

**EDIT**

This was not what you were asking for, but maybe the thing you really need.

Comment: That may be useful when optimizing very high-performance applications if there's an intensive calculation, but other than that isn't great practice. 1) if they want to check based on a date range, you can't use the pre-calculated answer, and 2) they then have to make it re-calculate every time a new set of hours are added.

Comment: 1) Then you could add an `running_hours` approach column to the `hours`-rows. Then if you want hours from 08-sep-12 to 10-sep-15 you take the running hours and calculate the difference. 2) Yes, but you insert one time a day for each user, and then it's only taking the previous max and add the hours for the day. It depends on how often he needs to calculate users work hours.

Comment: BTW, thank you for commenting. Sometimes people just downvote and move along, so you don't know what aspect they didn't like.